# Will running Cinnamon on 12.04 slow down ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, performance, cinnamon

I really like the Cinnamon interface ( already know how to get cinnamon on Ubuntu) Just need to know if it will slow down my computer. I use Unity on 12.04 Ubuntu

As requested here are my computer specs:

i5 2500k
8gb of ram
nvidia 7800 gtx